# Clickhouse dictionary. Search in the dictionary by part of a composite key

Tags: dictionary, clickhouse

I use dictionaries in clickhouse. First, I create a dictionary with one key, let's call it `dp_dim_channel_id` .

```
CREATE DICTIONARY IF NOT EXISTS dict_name_key_dp_dim_channel_id
    (
    dp_dim_channel_id String,
    dp_dim_channel_hash String,
    change_author Nullable(String),
    update_date_time Nullable(DateTime64(6)),
    channel_descr Nullable(String),
    sys_id UInt64
    )
    PRIMARY KEY dp_dim_channel_id
    SOURCE(CLICKHOUSE(
                    user 'user'
                    password 'password'
                    db 'db'
                    table 'dp_dim_channel'
        ))
    LIFETIME(20)
    LAYOUT(COMPLEX_KEY_HASHED());
```

I need this dictionary so that I can do a dictGet from another table and get the necessary values ​​by key. I'm doing this to get rid of join and speed up data retrieval.

```
SELECT dictGet('dict_name_key_dp_dim_channel_id', 'change_author', Data_public.some_table.`dp_dim_channel.dp_dim_channel_id`) as dict
    FROM db.some_table final;
```

Now, a situation arises that I need to access the same dictionary for another table, but using a different field, so I recreate the dictionary and my key becomes tuple(dp_dim_channel_id , dp_dim_channel_hash). I want to leave the ability to search for information in the dictionary only by part of the key (I use only key_1 or key_2). Let's assume that a particular part of the key is 100% unique.

So, I recreate dictionary:

```
CREATE DICTIONARY IF NOT EXISTS dict_name_key_dp_dim_channel_id_and_dp_dim_channel_hash
    (
    dp_dim_channel_id String,
    dp_dim_channel_hash String,
    change_author Nullable(String),
    update_date_time Nullable(DateTime64(6)),
    channel_descr Nullable(String),
    sys_id UInt64
    )
    PRIMARY KEY dp_dim_channel_id, dp_dim_channel_hash
    SOURCE(CLICKHOUSE(
                    user 'user'
                    password 'password'
                    db 'db'
                    table 'dp_dim_channel'
        ))
    LIFETIME(20)
    LAYOUT(COMPLEX_KEY_HASHED());
```

And now, I can only use this dictionary by explicitly specifying both keys.

```
SELECT dictGet('dict_name_key_dp_dim_channel_id_and_dp_dim_channel_hash', 'change_author', tuple(db.some_table.`dp_dim_channel.dp_dim_channel_id`, db.some_table.`dp_dim_channel.dp_dim_channel_hash`) as dict
    FROM db.some_table final;
```

Is it possible to do something like dictGet("dict_name", "column", tuple(key_1, any()))? How can I do that in dictGet syntax? Maybe there is some alternative?

Comment: So, only one workaround is to create separate dictionaries, each with a single part of the composite key. Then, perform a lookup in these dictionaries based on the available key part?